# Why does the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula not exist in $2$ or more dimensions?

Tags: calculus

The [Euler-Maclaurin summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_Maclaurin) relates a sum $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) $ to an integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$.

But why only for one dimension? Shouldn't we be able to generalize it to several dimensions?

Comment: It's Maclaurin, not mac Laurin...

Answer (score 1):

I would say in general it is not feasible.

One problem that I have encountered when trying to apply the EMSF to something like
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k+x}\sim\gamma_x+\log(n+x)+\frac1{2(n+x)}+O\left(\frac1{(n+x)^2}\right)
$$
is that $\gamma_x$ varies with $x$. Similar issues would arise in two-dimensional asymptotic expansions. The constant can be computed for a given value of one of the arguments, but usually not in general.